# How do I return an array in the reducer?

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, react-redux

I am making an app where I need to return boards as an array to map through in the Home component

Application state is (should be) something like this:

```
{
boardsList: {
    boards: An array of retrieved boards  
    boardCount: their length
    ...other stuff related to boards
},
```

The boardList reducer:

```
import {
    HOME_PAGE_LOADED,
    CHECK_IF_BOARD
} from '../constants/actiontypes'


const boards = (state = {}, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case HOME_PAGE_LOADED:
            return {
                ...state,
                boards: action.payload.boards
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}


export default boards;
```

The action payload:

```
payload:

boardCount: 2
boards: Array(2)
0: {_id: 1, name: "popps"}
1: {_id: 9, name: "sc"}
```

My Home Component that is retrieving boards:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { HOME_PAGE_LOADED, CHECK_IF_BOARD } from '../constants/actiontypes'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import agent from '../agent'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
     ...state.boardList
})


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onLoad: (payload) => {
        dispatch({ type: HOME_PAGE_LOADED, payload })
    },
    check: (payload) => {
        dispatch({ type: CHECK_IF_BOARD, payload })
    }
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home)
```

In my Home component, the type of this.props.boards is an object, however, the redux state shows it's an array!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your reducer because your state is nested. Change the reducer to:

```
switch (action.type) {
        case HOME_PAGE_LOADED:
            const boards = action.payload.boards || []
            return Object.assign({}, state, {boardsList: {boards, 
            boardCount:boards.length}})            
        default:
            return state
    }
```

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Using spread operator:

```
switch (action.type) {
        case HOME_PAGE_LOADED:
            const boards = action.payload.boards || []
            return ({...state, boardsList: {boards,
            boardCount:boards.length}})     
        default:
            return state
    }
```